# How to sort BagToTuple after group with pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have the data set as

```
id company
1  a
1  b
2  c
2  a
```

I wrote the code as following:
record = load....

```
grp = GROUP record BY id; 

newdata = FOREACH grp GENERATE group AS id, 
        COUNT(record) AS counts, 
        BagToTuple(record.company) AS company;
```

The output is looks like:

```
id count company
1  2     a,b
2  2     c,a
```

But I would like company can be sorted. For example, I need a,c for id 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Nested Foreach

```
newdata = FOREACH grp {
        sortedbag = order record by company;
        GENERATE group AS id,
        COUNT(sortedbag) AS counts,
        BagToTuple(sortedbag.company) AS company;
        };
```

Where the sortedbag alias contains the data sorted by company in ASCENDING order. In case if you want to sort in DESCENDING, change the statement to

```
sortedbag = order record by company DESC;
```